# Where can I find a complete list of keywords (of the form ${ ... } ) that can be used in netbeans "code template"

Tags: netbeans-8, code-templates

The complete list of keywords that are legal in creating code templates in Netbeans would be accompanied by some **documentation**, making the "list" a reference. A line from the reference might look like:

```
    ${cursor}       says to put the cursor at this point in the generated line
```

---

*Working examples* might be included in the reference, such as:

```
    User-defined word to invoke the template:         edfold
```

*The template as it would appear in the* `Netbeans 8.2 RC > Tools > Options > Editor > Code templates` tab:

```
    ${no-indent}//
    //  <editor-fold  desc="***** ${cursor} *****" >
    //
```

*How it works*: When I type `edfold` and hit the `Tab` key, the template is pasted into my document at the cursor position and looks like the following:

```
    //
    //  <editor-fold  desc="***** @ *****" >
    //
```

*The cursor is positioned between the 5th and 6th asterisks that follow* `desc`, *so that I can then type whatever brief documentation that I wish, if any.*

---

**So where is the list of such keywords and their syntax and meaning?** Such as:

`${cursor}
${selection}
${no-indent}
${arg}
${Type}`
and who knows how many more

It just hit me that there are *OTHER keywords*, two of which I unwittingly used above (I noticed them in someone else's code template and figured out how to use them):

```
    desc
    editor-fold
```

Surely there are other such identifiers to include in the reference.

---

*By the way, the code template above is cute (or not) but is useless without a companion code template:*

keypress:
`endfold`

*Code template in editor:*

```
// </editor-fold> ---------------- ${cursor} -------------------
```

*Wherever the first inserted code template is located in your code, the second template must be below it. There is a "collapse" symbol* "-" *at the left of the first template. Clicking it collapses the code between the two templates. The symbol then changes to* "+" *and will expand the collapsed code when clicked*.

---

***EDIT***
I just found [this equivalent code template to the edfold and endfold pair just completed](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding). Easier to code, up to a point, and harder to learn to use, but worth it, in the long run. Just highlight text to "hide" by folding, look for the line with the "Light Bulb", click Alt+Enter, and click "Code Folding". (Ctrl+Z to undo!)

But please see my (much better) Answer than this (was a) Question below.

Answer (score 0):

Egg on my  face... Googled topic, scanned all hits WAY too fast. In particular, "netbeans 8.2 code templates" pointed to [this page involving PHP (think Java)](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html), which contained a lot of invaluable info about PHP that applies directly to Code Templates in Netbeans 8.2.

So, that link is part of a *manual* of sorts for learning how to create Code Templates for Netbeans 8.2 (in particular, and PHP in general).

The *reference* that I asked for--*complete list of keywords* (of the form ${ … } )--implies a list of all keywords or reserved words, like `${cursor}` and `${selection}` that permeate the list of provided Code Templates. But in a sense, that is the list. It is exactly those two **Reserved Names**. There are no others. Short list.

In the list of provided Netbeans Code Templates, there are a LOT of words that share the same `$(...)` syntax, but most are **placeholder** names or **parameters** that you decide the name and (probably-simple) meaning of.

If a code template contains, for example, `class ${className}`, the word `class` is **Java code** and `${className}` is a parameter or placeholder. When the IDE expands the template, `class` is entered and `${className}` turns into **`class_name`**, which the IDE automatically selects for editing, suggesting for you to enter the name of the new Java class being defined.

[This non-trivial, but understandable, code template](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html#define) and much of what follows it explains much of the process for creating Code Templates. The heading `Inserting the code template with code completion` ends the explanation, but here is a sort of note of summary from further down:

```
    The syntax of a "code template parameter" is a dollar sign, $, followed by the
    parameter's definition between curly brackets {...}. Within this syntax, template 
    parameters have one of four forms:

    * A reserved name that gives processing instructions to IDE (cursor or selection, only)
    * An arbitrary placeholder name, such as ${SomeName}
    * A descriptive parameter name [that hints at its meaning]
    * Pre-defined parameters (??)
```